# PL/pgSQL function to populate an attribute with all NOT NULL values from other attributes

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function that, among others, will return an attribute that is populated with all NOT NULL values from two other INT type attributes from another table.

Additionally, the outcome has to be an attribute of varchar(12)

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_info_by_sponsor
       (select_date tb_register.register_ts%type, sponsor tb_sponsor.name%type)
RETURNS SETOF sponsor_data LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
      sponsor sponsor_data;
BEGIN
      SELECT
             tb_sponsor.email,
             tb_finance.sponsor_name,
             tb_athlete.name,
             tb_discipline.name,
             tb_register.round_number, 
             COALESCE(CAST(tb_register.register_time AS varchar(12)),CAST(tb_register.register_measure AS varchar(12)),
             tb_register.register_position,
             DATE(tb_register.register_ts)
                
       INTO sponsor
       FROM olympic.tb_sponsor
       
       INNER JOIN olympic.tb_finance
           ON (tb_finance.sponsor_name = tb_sponsor.name)
       INNER JOIN olympic.tb_athlete
           ON tb_athlete.athlete_id = tb_finance.athlete_id
       INNER JOIN olympic.tb_register
           ON tb_register.athlete_id = tb_athlete.athlete_id
       INNER JOIN olympic.tb_discipline
           ON tb_discipline.discipline_id = tb_register.discipline_id
       ORDER BY sponsor;

      RETURN NEXT sponsor ;
END ;  
$$;
```

I was trying to use COALESCE, but I am not sure if it is possible to use attributes as COALESCE expression values?

Can anyone help me understand what is the solution to this problem?

Thank you (:

Addinf some sample data:

```
athlete_id, round_number, discipline_id, register_date, register_positon, register_time, register_measure,


"1320573"   0   1   "2021-06-02"    0       29.5
"1304325"   0   1   "2021-06-02"    1       29.57
"1281372"   0   1   "2021-06-03"    2       29.65
"1378860"   0   1   "2021-06-04"    3       29.75
"1324035"   0   1   "2021-06-01"    4       29.79
"1429024"   0   1   "2021-06-02"    5       29.82
"1346893"   0   1   "2021-06-04"    6       29.85
"1324053"   0   1   "2021-06-03"    7       29.89
"1324193"   0   1   "2021-06-04"    8       29.96
"1323940"   0   1   "2021-06-01"    9       30.02
"1444814"   1   2   "2021-06-04"    1   "00:10:57"  
"1355032"   1   2   "2021-06-08"    2   "00:11:00"  
"1870169"   1   2   "2021-06-06"    3   "00:11:06"  
"1458862"   1   2   "2021-06-08"    4   "00:11:14"  
"1354946"   1   2   "2021-06-09"    5   "00:11:21"  
"1323812"   1   2   "2021-06-06"    6   "00:11:30"  
"1281464"   1   2   "2021-06-08"    7   "00:11:32"  
"1305865"   1   2   "2021-06-09"    8   "00:11:40"  
"1354902"   1   2   "2021-06-06"    9   "00:11:45"  
"1461993"   2   2   "2021-06-13"    0   "00:10:04"  
"1479209"   2   2   "2021-06-12"    1   "00:10:14"  
"1377716"   2   2   "2021-06-13"    2   "00:10:18"  
"1876984"   2   2   "2021-06-14"    3   "00:10:25"  
"1475004"   2   2   "2021-06-10"    4   "00:10:31"  
"1324488"   2   2   "2021-06-10"    5   "00:10:36"
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by first? `Coalesce` examines each argument value in the order they are listed, it returns the first value in the order examined that is not null. If all arguments are null it returns null. To prevent that you supply a default not null as the last argument ,

Comment: @Belayer the attributes  register_time and register_measure have some null values. What I want to achieve is to create another attribute x  that will contain all not null values from both register_time and register_measure. I tried to use Coalesce but it does not work, and this is why I have asked the question here (:

Comment: If I understand the description then no `coalesce` **cannot do that**. Coalesce selects alternatives, the description seems to suggest what you are looking for is the [concat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html) function (not the operator, || ). But by all do you mean within each row of collectively across all rows, Then  [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html) in an outer query.  Best if you post sample data (both with and without nulls) and expected results of that date, as text - **no images**.

Comment: @Belayer sample data added. You can now see that whenever register_measure is NULL register_time is NOT NULL and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

The  `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not null, otherwise the second is returned, Null is returned only if all arguments are null.
Check the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```
select COALESCE(null, 'hello');
hello

select COALESCE('text', 'hello');
text
```

Comment: thank you! I know this part of theory and documentation. But this does not answer my question. My question is how to, if possible,  use COALESCE to populate an attribute with no null values from other attributes, not how to find first, not null value.